# How Could I use git log --oneline --all output for ubuntu which will be the same as look like mac, when I will use git bisect good/bad command

Tags: git-log, git-bisect

I have set the both git bisect good and bad commit but for Ubuntu refs/bisect/bad and good is missing. So how could I bring it back in ubuntu for the same command( git log --oneline --all).

This is in mac git log --oneline --all command output

[image: 1]

This is in Ubuntu git log --oneline --all command output

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

`git log --oneline --all --clear-decorations` will show you the bisect refs